# how to use regular expression match information in a file in TCL?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a file stored in the terminal server and there are some inforation stored in the file I want to use TCL and regular expression to match.

how could I achieve this? do I need to open the file in order to use the regluar expression?
can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Conceptually, you read the file into memory and then use a regular expression to get the information you want. For very large files, you benefit from reading a piece at a time (e.g., a line) and applying the regular expression to that, but then you might have to deal with multi-line patterns, which can make code quite a bit more tricky.

Reading the file in might require you to copy it across to the local machine first. (You can often avoid actually creating a file locally, but not always.) Or you relocate the place where the Tcl program runs to be next to the original file; that can work just as well in general.

Assuming you've got a very simple case:

```
# Use scp to bring file across; _many_ other options possible
exec scp otherhost:file.txt localfile.txt

# Read in the file:
set f [open localfile.txt]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Get the interesting bits...
if {[regexp {MATCH_THIS: (\d+)} $data -> theNumber]} {
    # Found a match, number in $theNumber
}
```

Comment: the file is stored in a vob of clearcase, I specify the whole path of this file, but it tells me: couldn't open it no such file or directory, are there any special in clearcase to specify the path?

Comment: @ratzip, update your question with exact snippet of the code you're using to access the file. Otherwise it's plain guesseneering on our part which is not productive most of the time.

Comment: what is the last part mean:if {[regexp {MATCH_THIS: (\d+)} $data -> theNumber]} {
    # Found a match, number in $theNumber
}

Comment: @ratzip You should try to work out as much of that as possible for yourself. It's a common Tcl idiom. (The lines starting with `#` are comments…)